# How to programatically open a dialog in jquery mobile alpha 4?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I inject html for dialog via script like:

```
 $("#misc-cntr").append('<div id="chk" data-rel="dialog" > </div>');
```

then in ajax success callback I have:

```
success: function(msg) {
$('#chk').html(msg)
 // open dialog here
//  $('#chk').dialog('open')  does not work
}
```

Given above how can I open the dialog programatically?

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to change the page to it, something along the lines of:

```
$.mobile.changePage($('#chk'), 'pop', false, true);
```

If you want to close the dialog via javascript, you'll need:

```
$('#chk').dialog('close');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your tip helped to make the dialog show up but the dialog pops up and shows up for a fraction of a second and then disappears. Not sure what is causing this problem.

Comment: Can you post a bit more of your code, or better yet, toss it into a JSFiddle so we can see what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I used. It's very dirty, but it uses an actual dialog instead of a popping page.

The div:

```
<div data-role="page" id="score" data-theme="d" data-transition="pop" />
```

The jQuery code:

```
var a = $('<a />').attr({
    href: '#score',
    "data-rel": 'dialog'
}).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

The changePage function takes an object as second argument. In it you can specify things as role and transition. For your case you need to set role to 'dialog'.

```
$.mobile.changePage( $('#chk'), { role: 'dialog', transition: 'slide'} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.mobile.changePage($('#mydialog'),{'transition':'pop'});
```

OR

```
$.mobile.changePage($('#mydialog'),'pop');
```